# Both of the input box has exactly same attributes. How do I take unique xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

https://www.phptravels.net has two input boxes with same name and same attributes (Enter City Or Airport).Consequently, my xpath results in "no such element" exception. Is there any work around. Please help! Following are the code:

```
 package com.php.travels;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Booking {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
   "/Users/owner/desktop/chromedriver");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Flights']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2- 
    drop']/div/input")).sendKeys("LAX");

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about same ID for both elements.

The id will be changed when you click on the text field. It means you will find only single input element each time. You don't need to worry if they have the same ID or not.

You have to click at the text field before finding the input element. See my code below.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Flights']")));
element.click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_location_from']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2-drop']/div/input")).sendKeys("LAX");
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='select2-results']//li[contains(.,'LAX')]")));
element.click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='s2id_location_to']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='select2-drop']/div/input")).sendKeys("DMK");
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='select2-results']//li[contains(.,'DMK')]")));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the input boxes have different names

```
<input type="text" name="" id="location_from" tabindex="-1" class="select2-offscreen">
<input type="text" name="" id="location_to" tabindex="-1" class="select2-offscreen">
```

So you can have the following css selectors for the first and second input boxes

For first input box : `input#location_from.select2-offscreen`

For second input box : `input#location_to.select2-offscreen`

I have tried both these locators and they work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the locators only if you can get the exact locator then there would not be the problem:

```
 package com.php.travels;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Booking {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
   "/Users/owner/desktop/chromedriver");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='hidden-xs' and contains(text(),'Flights')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='select2-chosen' and contains(text(),'Enter City Or Airport')]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2-drop-mask']/following-sibling::div//input[contains(@class,'select2-input')]")).sendKeys("LAX");
   }

}
```